# Why doesn't suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier work?

Tags: php, security, suhosin, php-5.6

I'm running PHP5.6 on ubuntu12.04 as apache 2.4 module
Suhosin is installed from sources

Suhosin is enabled and I can see it in phpinfo() function output.
I have these lines in the suhosin.ini:

```
suhosin.executor.disable_eval = On
suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier = On
```

And I can also see them enabled in phpinfo(). Both globally and locally.

But for some reason simple

```
eval('echo 5;');
```

just shows me the damn “5”!!!

Same does

```
preg_replace("/.*/e", "eval('echo 5, PHP_EOL;')", ".");
```

How do I enable that suhosin?

Comment: How did you get PHP5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: There are two ways: you either build it from the sources or google for some repo. I did the second thing.

Comment: And which repo exactly did you get? I'm only asking because I want to get the exact same package as you did to try and reproduce your issue, you know? I don't need to know all the ways you can do it, just your specific one is enough.

Comment: Sorry :)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check both local and master values in your `phpinfo()` for the lines `suhosin.executor.disable_eval` and `suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier` in order to be sure that the configuraton file is read correctly, and not only for the activation of suhosin.

The local value of those directive should be set to 'On'.

If the local is Off but the master is On, then your virtualhost configuration might override this parameter. If both are Off, then you're suhosin.ini is not parsed correctly

**You also have to chech that `suhosin.simulation` (debug mode) is set to `Off`.**

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post I checked the values with phpinfo() and they both were set to “On”.

Comment: You only mentionned that you could see that suhosin was enabled, not that "**local** values" of configuration parameters were both set to "On" (and not only the "master value") when you do a phpinfo(). If such is the case, you should edit your question to make it really clear. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @KonstantinBodnya Still waiting for your feedback, please confirm, that your **local** values are set to 'On' in your phpinfo()

Comment: Yes. Of course they are both set to “On” globally and locally.

Comment: I'm glad, i had nothing more left to say ;-)